# JQuery Image Preview not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing

I've seen several ways to display image preview but none of them seem to work or they work only in FF/Chrome.

Trying to keep it simple:

Markup:

```
<input type="file" id="logo-upload" onchange="changePreview();"/>
<br/>        
<img src='@Url.Image("logo.png")' alt="Preview" id="logo-preview"/>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function changePreview() {

        var input = $('#logo-upload').val();

         $('#logo-preview').attr('src', input)
                    .width(150)
                    .height(50);
         }

</script>
```

When debugging `input` shows the correct local image path but preview never shows up.
Why and how can I get this to work (in all browsers ) ?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have a `<form>` containing that `<input>`?

Comment: I don't know if this is a copy paste issue but your quotes need to be fixed `<img src="@Url.Image("logo.png")" alt="Preview" id="logo-preview"/>`

Comment: wirey copy/paste thing
@Rodolfo Yes but the form will be submitted only after the "preview" looks good to the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `$('#logo-upload').change(function(){})` instead of using onChange.  I think that's a good start.  Then put the jQuery inside `$(document).ready(function(){})`.  That could be another issue, if you're setting the script before the elements exist on the page.

If you can post more code, it would be beneficial.

Also, for IE, you're going to run into permissions issues that are on the user, which you don't have control over (at least in this situation).  So, in those cases, you'll either have to upload the image first, to get the image from the server, OR they'll have to change their security settings to allow for this type of content to be accessed.

```
<input type="file" id="logo-upload" />
<br/>        
<img src="@Url.Image('logo.png')" alt="Preview" id="logo-preview"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#logo-upload').change(function() {
            var input = $(this).val();
            $('#logo-preview').attr('src', input).width(150).height(50);
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not really different from what I did in OP and unfortunately not working either. Tried IE and Chrome

Comment: This is different than what you did in the OP.  This way, things are encapsulated properly, so be sure that they will work, and you aren't mixing old DHTML methods with DOM events.  Moreover, I addressed an issue in IE which is preventing this particular way of previewing an image.  If you want to get more accessibility on the client side, you're going to have to get into the FileAPI in HTML5.

Comment: Also, in the current state of the browsers, I'm pretty sure you won't be able to do a file preview in ALL without first uploading the file to the server (which may defeat the point of the preview). http://caniuse.com/filereader

Comment: It seems to me the permission issue you've mentioned is the #1 concern and really is the cause of my problems. Can't do HTML5 because it not a standard yet :( Possibly there is a way to pass the image to the server method, shrink it and return it via $.ajax request? ... I'm looking into it right now.